# How to provide feedback that an error occurred in the error handling methods of a class?

Tags: python

I am working with a class in python that is part of a bigger program. The class is calling different methods.

If there is an error in one of the method I would like code to keep running after, but after the program is finished, I want to be able to see which methods had potential errors in them.

Below is roughly how I am structuring it at the moment, and this solution doesn't scale very well with more methods. Is there a better way to provide feedback (after the  code has been fully run) as to which of the method had a potential error?

```
class Class():

    def __init__(self):

        try: 
             self.method_1()
        except:
             self.error_method1 = "Yes"
             break

        try: 
             self.method_2()
        except: 
             self.error_method2 = "Yes"
             break

        try: 
             self.method_3()
        except: 
             self.error_method3 = "Yes"
             break
```

Comment: You don't need to manually do this, the stack trace in the exception would tell you

Comment: Let me clarify. This one class is part of a bigger code. The code continue working if there is an error in one of the methods. It should just provide direct feedback so I can fix it later.

Comment: When an exception occurs, you can call [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) in the `except:` clause to get information about what happened. At that point, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I don't think that is his issue.  He is wanting to use the same message for all method calls of his class?

Comment: So you're trying to invent your own application error logger?

Comment: @James: By saving information about which error occurred, specific "feedback" about precisely what went wrong could be provided at  a later time.

Comment: @martineau I am not disagreeing with you.  I was just trying to clarify the original problem.

Comment: MathiasRa: BTW, using `break` statements as you show in those `except` clauses would cause `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` errors all by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) to retrieve information about an `Exception` when one occurs as I mentioned in a comment, doing so may not be required since Python's standard `try`/`expect` mechanism seems adequate.

Below is a runnable example showing how to do so in order to provide "feedback" later about the execution of several methods of a `class`. This approach uses a decorator function, so should scale well since the same decorator can be applied to as many of the class' methods as desired.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps
import sys
from textwrap import indent


def provide_feedback(method):
    """ Decorator to trap exceptions and add messages to feedback. """

    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            self._feedback.append(
                '{!r} exception occurred in {}()'.format(exc, method.__qualname__))

    return wrapped_method


class Class():

    def __init__(self):
        with self.feedback():
            self.method_1()
            self.method_2()
            self.method_3()

    @contextmanager
    def feedback(self):
        self._feedback = []
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            # Example of what could be done with any exception messages.
            # They could instead be appended to some higher-level container.
            if self._feedback:
                print('Feedback:')
                print(indent('\n'.join(self._feedback), '  '))

    @provide_feedback
    def method_1(self):
        raise RuntimeError('bogus')

    @provide_feedback
    def method_2(self):
        pass

    @provide_feedback
    def method_3(self):
        raise StopIteration('Not enough foobar to go around')


inst = Class()
```

Output:

```
Feedback:
  RuntimeError('bogus') exception occurred in Class.method_1()
  StopIteration('Not enough foobar to go around') exception occurred in Class.method_3()
```

Comment: MathiasRa: Is this along the lines of what you desired?